# Revert all commits in branch and make clean copy of master

Tags: git

I have my feature branch which is created from master branch. I did some changes which I want revert back. In short I want feature branch which will be looks like after creation. After that reverts, I need do some changes and push it on bitbucket with amend parameter to the commit which is on server exist.

Comment: On a side note, branches are not "copies" of `master`. Every branch is a pointer to a commit in your repository's history. You cannot copy a branch, but you can create a new pointer (branch) which points to the same commit as another branch. I strongly recommend reading this page from the Git Book which will help you understand how to work with branches: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is

Comment: @gucce thanks, I guess I need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
git checkout .
```

or

```
git reset --hard <commit>
```

To remove untracked files:

```
git clean -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new branch from the master.

If you really want to revert for some reason, then you can use

```
git reset --hard <commit_you_want_to_go_back_to>
```